# Post mortem debugging with the MSVC .map file

Tags: visual-c++, postmortem-debugging

I have deployed a Windows application, which crashes sporadically. I built the application in release mode without debug symbols, but with the /MAP option in order to track down bugs after the fact.

The error message is:

> "Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF63113DA4D in App.exe: 0xC0000005:
>   Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000000."

So I need to find out where 0x00007FF63113DA4D is.

The App.map files begins with

```
Preferred load address is 0000000140000000
```

And a typical entry:

```
  Address         Publics by Value              Rva+Base               Lib:Object
0001:000ecff0       ?FUNCTION@CLASS@@QEBAHXZ 00000001400edff0 f   STATICLIB:FILE.obj
```

So, how do I relate an adress beginning with "000000014" to the one in the error message beginning with "0x00007FF"?